# Get file content as a vector: Borrowed value does not live long enough

Tags: string, vector, rust

I tried to get a file content as a vector. Reading the documentation, I thought I have to do it like this (simplified code, I removed error handling):

```
use std::fs::File;
use std::path::Path;
use std::io::Read;

fn main() {
    let mut s = String::new();
    let c: Vec<&str> = match open_or_die("test.txt").read_to_string(&mut s) {
        Err(why) => panic!("fail"),
        Ok(_) => s,
    }.to_string().split("\n").collect();
    println!("{}", c[0]);
}    

fn open_or_die(filename: &str) -> File {
    File::open(&Path::new(filename)).unwrap()
}
```

But I've got a problem with lifetimes:

```
error: borrowed value does not live long enough
```

I'm still lost with lifetimes. Reading [the doc](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.split), I thought it should work.

What should I do to get a string slices as a vector?

Comment: Don't ask me why, but it works if you do it in two steps. See https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=c41c369ce69ed2f03fbf8c24fa3961ea&version=stable&backtrace=0

Comment: The `String` in `s` is moved into a temporary variable at the end of the match, which ceases to exist at the end of that expression. The superfluous `to_string()` only makes it worse.

Comment: And its not really a duplicate of that question. There the issue is that the return value references a string whose lifetime ends at the end of the block.

Comment: Next time, please post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) yourself.

Comment: "And its not really a duplicate of that question." @starblue Do you think I should reopen it?